# random picture script for new app

Tags: javascript, html, image, random

I am creating an app through AppMaker and I want a random picture to appear when someone clicks the icon.  I found a script online. I entered the script in (where they accept html on a screen) and it doesn't seem to run when I test it.  I created several test pictures and uploaded them to my online site and then ran this script. Any help would be appreciated.
The script is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var total_images = 2;
    var random_number = Math.floor((Math.random(2)*total_images));
    var random_img = new Array(3);
    random_img[0] = '<a href="http://mymoonspirit.com/images/Tarot1.jpg"><img src="images/Tarot1.jpg"></a>';;
    random_img[1] = '<a href="http://mymoonspirit.com/images/Tarot2.jpg"><img src="images/Tarot2.jpg"></a>';;
    document.write(random_img[random_number]);
</script>`
```

Comment: You have `;` two times in line `random_img[0] = ...` and `random_img[1] = ...`. Is that a typing mistake?

Comment: I was just copying a script and adding my location. Yes a typo, but I was not sure if it was suppose to be there.  Thanks.

Comment: No. There should be only 1 `;`. Also, if there are only 2 images, make `randon_img` array of size 2 only. It's of size 3 in your current code.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked around and this looks like the best solution;

```
var image-number = Math.floor(Math.random() * random_img.length);
var image = random_img[image-number];
```

Comment: Oh thank you. Just to be sure, does this replace line 3and4? And is this how it is suppose to look? Or should I do away with the entire old script?

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var total_images = 2;
    var image-number = Math.floor(Math.random() * random_img.length);
    var image = random_img[image-number];
    random_img[0] = '<a href="http://mymoonspirit.com/images/Tarot1.jpg"><img src="images/Tarot1.jpg"></a>';;
    random_img[1] = '<a href="http://mymoonspirit.com/images/Tarot2.jpg"><img src="images/Tarot2.jpg"></a>';;
    document.write(random_img[random_number]);
</script>`